# Number of rainy days per year in a given city

Tags: data-request, weather, meteorology

I'm looking for a dataset that could allow me to compute, or better give me directly;

1. How many days per year a city x experiences some rain for more than y hours.
2. How many days per year a city x experiences some rain for more than z mm of rains at time.

(where x, y and z are specified by the user)

E.g. how many days per year Seattle experiences more than two hours of rain.

Comment: Do you need global dataset or for a specific country?

Comment: @PadmanabhaChowdhury I'm mostly interested in the US but happy to get data for other countries as well

Comment: You can find rainfall data for all US cities from [NOAA](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/search).

Comment: @PadmanabhaChowdhury very cool, thanks! You are welcome to convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

All the climate data of US are available on the National Climatic Data Center, under the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration (NOAA). You can get county, city or state based rainfall, wind etc. data of both recent and historical times.

Data link: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/search